# How to determine if a point lies inside a polygon in 3D space?

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, point-in-polygon

I have a 3D point P(x,y,z) and a polygon S defined by arbitrary amount of 3D points. The polygon is not necessary convex (so in my opinion, the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311682) do not answer my question), but P is in the same plane as S. Now, I need to determine if the P lies inside of S.

For example:

```py
polygon = np.array([[6173.953125  , 9689.90136719,  298.03326416],
       [6173.95410156, 9689.90136719,  298.09350586],
       [6173.89355469, 9689.86621094,  298.23690796],
       [6173.89355469, 9689.86621094,  298.23690796],
       [6173.83496094, 9689.83398438,  298.5083313 ],
       [6173.89453125, 9689.86816406,  298.38320923],
       [6173.89697266, 9689.87011719,  298.44348145],
       [6173.89697266, 9689.87011719,  298.44348145],
       [6173.953125  , 9689.90136719,  298.03326416],
       [6173.89355469, 9689.86621094,  298.23690796],
       ...
       ])

point = np.array([6171.37079656, 9688.35796064,  309.00229108])
```

Example Image: Point outside Polygon:
[image]

In this example, it is obvious that the result should be "False" (point is outside).

Using the point:

```py
point2 = np.array([6173.83496094, 9689.83398438, 297.72579346])
```

the result should be "True" (point is in polygon).

Example Image: Point inside Polygon:
[image]

I know, I basically have to solve a simple Point-in-Polygon (PiP) problem. However, is there a package that includes such a function directly? Or how can I transform all the points to apply PiP algorithms provided by shapely or similar packages?

Comment: Is not a polygon convex by definition?

Comment: @BlueRineS No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon

Comment: Is that polygon planar ? If not, no points can be "inside" it.

Comment: The polygons are planar.

Comment: If the segments were square though, you could have used AABB (axis aligned bounding box)

Comment: google: `hit test` and `perpendicular distance between point and plane` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding if point is in 3D poly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311682/finding-if-point-is-in-3d-poly-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `P is in the same plane as S` is guaranteed, make (virtual) projection of polygon and point onto any coordinate plane (not perpendicular to polygon plane). For example, to make projection onto OXZ (suitable for the second example), just ignore Y-components.

Then use any algorithm intended for 2D ([pnpoly](https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu//Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html))

Comment: Thank you for the hint and especially for the link. After projection in 2D, I could just use the `point.within(polygon)` from the `shapely` package.

Comment: I used the method of eliminating the X,Y,Z dimension with the smallest difference between the min and max values. But I find there were corner cases that lead to errors. To make sure I always got the correct answer I did the following:

Comment: I found the projection method had corner cases that lead to errors. To make sure I always got the correct answer I did the following: 1) subtract point0 from all the points so point0 is at the origin. 2) rotate all the points around the Z and Y axes so point1 sits on the X axis. 3) rotate all the points around the X axis so point2 and all other points have a Z value of zero and sit on the XY plane. 4) then  use pnpoly to determine if the point (also translated and rotated the same amounts) is inside or outside the polygon.  Doesn't take that much longer, and works every time.