# Interpolation Mask at boundary

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, plotly

I am wanting to generate a heatmap of the gradients between the Z-Values and display using Plotly.

The issue I have is being able to effectively mask the unwanted data that forms from interpolation in 'concave' areas which don't have datapoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (maybe not the most elegant) would be to find the boundary of the points (concave hull) and then set anything outside of this boundary to `nan`.

To find the boundary you can use [alphashape](https://github.com/bellockk/alphashape) and to determine if the `grid_z` points are inside (or on) the boundary you can use [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html).

Here is an example that picks up right before the first plotly plots:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import alphashape

mpoints = [Point(X, Y) for X, Y in zip(x, y)]

alpha=.125
hull = alphashape.alphashape(mpoints, alpha)
poly = Polygon(hull)

grid_gz = grid_z
gx = np.arange(min(x), max(x),1)
gy = np.arange(min(y), max(y),1)
for i, gxi in enumerate(gx):
    for j, gyi in enumerate(gy):
        if not np.isnan(grid_gz[j,i]): #UPDATE: no need to test pts that are already NaN
            p1 = Point(gxi, gyi)
            test = poly.contains(p1) | poly.touches(p1)
            if test==False:
                grid_gz[j,i]=np.nan

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Heatmap(z=grid_gz,x0=min(x),y0=min(y),showscale=True, zsmooth='best', 
               connectgaps=False, colorscale='Hot'
               ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,mode="markers",marker_size=2,marker_color="black",
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    width = 1200,
    height = 1200,
    title = "Gradient Heatmap Plot",
    yaxis = dict(
      scaleanchor = "x",
      scaleratio = 1,
    ))

fig.show()
```

Further Comments:

- I ended up manually selecting the alpha value.  You can use `optimizealpha` to find the alpha value, BUT this value ended up being a little too course and the one edge had steps in the heatmap.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378168/11305111) as well.
- More information can be found [here](https://alphashape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alphashape.html#examples-using-alphashape-alphashape) on `alphashape`.
- More information can be found [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.contains) on shapely's `contains` and [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.touches) on `touches`

[image]

Comment: Wow thank-you so much Jayveesea! This helps me out so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I may post an update if I have time, but I think this could be improved by only testing the non-nan `grid_z` results.