# Points in convex hull and assign True/False to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, convex-hull

Here's my starting point, I have the following two point datasets

```
data1 = {'x': [580992.9581, 580992.9111, 580993.3539, 580993.4957, 580991.9780],
         'y': [4275268.7194, 4275267.6678, 4275267.2215, 4275268.1749, 4275267.6297]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'x': [580992.7155, 580993.4258, 580992.7421, 580991.7034, 580992.7554, 580993.5837, 580993.0002, 580993.8348, 580991.2176, 580992.0536],
         'y': [4275267.2733, 4275267.7455, 4275266.7449, 4275268.8644, 4275266.4493, 4275267.5785, 4275268.5525, 4275268.9687, 4275267.6972, 4275267.7937]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I'm wanting to, in the most efficient way, calculate the Convex Hull of each of the dataframes, then determine which points are in the convex hull of the other dataframe.

So create the `hull_of_df1` and the `hull_of_df2`.

To do this either Scipy's `ConvexHull(df1)' or in Shapely, let's use scipy.

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
hull_of_df1 = ConvexHull(df1)
hull_of_df2 = ConvexHull(df2)
```

Now, I need to assign `True` to any points from `df1` that are in `hull_of_df2`.

The long way to do this would be something like:

```
for point in df1:
    if point.within(hull_of_df2):
        df1['in_hull'] = True
    else:
        df1['in_hull'] = False
```

And repeat for the other dataframe and other convex hull.

Ideally I just want to generate a new column and append it to the end of the `df1` dataframe. So for those indexes which are within `df1` assign `in_hull == True`. I do not want to delete any points in the dataframes, just record which points are and arn't in the opposite convex hull.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your current method is and whether it gives you the desired result. Can you post a working code snippet and the correct result? Then it's easier for us to think about more efficient solutions.

Comment: This question seems related. Are any of the answers here relevant? [What's an efficient way to find if a point lies in the convex hull of a point cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750618/whats-an-efficient-way-to-find-if-a-point-lies-in-the-convex-hull-of-a-point-cl)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16898636/1609514) from above linked question works with your data: `df1['in_hull'] = in_hull(df1, df2)` gives `[True, True, False, True,True]`. I haven't checked to see how efficient it is on a larger set of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hull equations do determine if the point is inside the hull

```py
def in_hull(points, hull):
    A = hull.equations
    dist = np.array(points[['x', 'y']]) @ A[:,:2].T + A[:,2]
    return np.all(dist < 0, axis=1)

df1['within'] = in_hull(df1, hull_of_df2);
df2['within'] = in_hull(df2, hull_of_df1);
```

With some plotting to be more convincing

```py
plt.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'], '.r')
for r in hull_of_df1.simplices:
    plt.plot(df1['x'][r], df1['y'][r], '-r')
plt.plot(df2['x'], df2['y'], '.g')
for r in hull_of_df2.simplices:
    plt.plot(df2['x'][r], df2['y'][r], '-g')

df1['within'] = in_hull(df1, hull_of_df2);
mr = df1['within']
plt.plot(df1['x'][mr], df1['y'][mr], 'xg')

df2['within'] = in_hull(df2, hull_of_df1);
mr = df2['within']
plt.plot(df2['x'][mr], df2['y'][mr], 'xr')
```

[image]