# How to filter points appearing in a list of convex hull polygons?

Tags: python, convex-hull

I have 2 dataframes df & df1 :

df : containing latitude, longitude and binary cluster (0 or 1)

```
latitude    Longitude    cluster 
30.400091   -100.722830   0
30.500091   -100.762830   0
30.600091   -100.792830   1
...
```

df1 :

```
latitude    Longitude    
31.400091   -100.722830   
32.501091   -101.862830   
32.600091   -100.792830 
...
```

For df, I applied convex hull in order to obtain 2 polygons (the two polygon are separaten no crossing zone between them) for each cluster 0 and 1 with the following code :

```
z=[] #HULL simplices coordinates will be appended here

for i in range (0,num_clusters):
    dfq=df[df['cluster']==i]
    Y = np.array(dfq[['Latitude', 'Longitude']])
    hull = ConvexHull(Y)
    plt.plot(Y[:, 1],Y[:, 0],  'o')
    z.append(Y[hull.vertices,:].tolist())
```

I also have a unique polygon for df1 :

```
hull1 = ConvexHull(df1)
```

I would like to know, if is possible to filter/conserve df1 points which strictly apear in one of the df polygons ? [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149964/points-in-convex-hull-and-assign-true-false-to-the-dataframe) is quite similar but do not works for a list a polygons like in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most efficient solution, but it will certainly work.

First convert the dataframe data to a python list or numpy array.

For the desired hull, You can convert the hull to a `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` using its constructor

```
import shapely.geometry    
# Hull is a list of 2D coordinates, e.g. hull=[(1.0,5.0),(-1.0,3.0),(7.0,7.0)]
mypolygon = shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon(hull)
```

Use `mypolygon.contains(shapely.geometry.point.Point(test_x,test_y))` to check if a point lies inside the polygon.

You can then discard the data for the unwanted polygon, and convert the desired data back to a dataframe.